# how do you style content when querying a data structure nested n-levels deep?

Tags: mvc

This question has come up while writing a simple text adventure game where your character has an inventory, which can include containers that also have things in them. I want a clean way to style the inventory output, like so:

```
You are carrying:
    a bag containing:
        a ring
    a backpack containing:
        a loaf of bread
```

Currently I just include the formatting in the result returned by the query, all in one shot. For example,

```
DoInventoryCommand():
    result = QueryInventory(...recursively checks inventory adding multiples of tabs depending on nesting level...)
    print(result)
```

What I would like is a cleaner separation between content and presentation so that the query would just return a data structure that a separate pass could style.

But how should the styling pass handle the n-levels deep data structure? Just for example, how would a styling tool like CSS handle it? Do you need to procedurally generate the CSS once you have the data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure should be recursive, like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public override string GetString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

Add four spaces to the beginning of the display line for each new recursion level.  You can maintain a "level" variable that you pass along during the recursion (or make it static), increment it during each recursive call, and decrement it during each recursive `return`.

```
int indent = 0;
public string GetDisplayString()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder(new string(' ', indent) + node.ToString());
    if (node.Children != null)
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            indent += 4;
            s.Append(GetString(child));
            indent -= 4;
        }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks Robert, however this is basically what I have now (the indent is managed as you build the query response). Is there a case for returning just the data structure and then styling it as a separate procedure?